# Safari bug with CSS columns

Tags: css, image, safari

I have this strange bug in Safari Mac. When I use CSS columns (-webkit-column-count), the column break cuts the image in half instead of breaking the column after the image.

In FF & Chrome everything goes like it supposed to be.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

I've attached 2 screenshots and the current url where it's happening:
http://omloophetnieuwsblad.be/nl/elite-men/news/2011-02/35/langeveld-wint-de-omloop

1. Safari bug
   [image: Safari Bug]
2. Correct columns
   [image: Correct columns]

Comment: Currently I'm using Safari 5.0.3. I've just tested the site in Safari 5.1 on Lion, and the bug seems to be solved there, so it's the matter of time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a known safari bug... Just have to wait for them to fix it.

A somewhat ok fix for now would be to give the div.entry a height to accommodate the image. I tried 630px and it looked fine

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found a way to solve this easily.

You can use this CSS element:

`-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;`